# How to make red for every 3n-2 item of enumerate items?

Tags: programming

I want to automatically make red for every item with remainder of 1 when divided by 3. Manually wrapping the `3n-2` items with `\textcolor{}` will be an absurd idea especially in the current AI era.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{red}{$3xy^2-5xy$}
\item $-2x^2y^3+14x^2y^2$
\item $-2a^2b-4ab^2+8ab$

\item \textcolor{red}{$2x^2+10xy-3xy-15y^2$}
\item $m^2-mn-mn+n^2$
\item $2\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta-3\alpha\beta-3\beta^2$

\item \textcolor{red}{$-2 x^2+13 x y-15 y^2$}
\item $-5 m^2-7 m n+6 n^2$
\item $-14 p^2+29 p q+15 q^2$


\item $-2 a^2-5 a b+12 b^2$
\item $8 r^2+14 r s-15 s^2$

\item $a^2-b^2$
\item $x^2-y^2$
\item $x^2-5x+6$
\item $x^3-5x^2+6x$
\item $-10x^2+17x-3$
\item $15x^2+23x-28$

\item $-30x^2-52x+42$
\item $30x^2-52x-42$
\item $-20x^2-52x+63$
\item $20x^2-52x-63$

\item $-30x^2+12x+42$
\item $30x^2+12x-42$
\item $-20x^2+12x+63$
\item $20x^2+12x-63$

\item $30x^2-73x+42$
\item $-30x^2-73x-42$
\item $20x^2-73x+63$
\item $-20x^2-73x-63$

\item $30x^2+71x+42$
\item $-30x^2+71x-42$
\item $20x^2+71x+63$
\item $-20x^2+71x-63$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with AI, though.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz: Thank  you for your solution. I have to wait for a couple of hours as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `enumitem` package don't have item hooks, so I manually patched `\@item`.

Current setting will only color items used in the first level of `enumerate`. That is, items of nested list environments will not be colored.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{
  before*={
    \let\@item@orig\@item
    \pretocmd\@item
      {\normalcolor}
      {}{\fail}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \apptocmd\@item
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT { \int_mod:nn{\use:c{c@\@listctr}}{3} } = {1}
          { \color{red} }
      }
      {}{\fail}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
  }
}

\setlist[2]{
  before*=\normalcolor\let\@item\@item@orig
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $3xy^2-5xy$
\begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item a
  \item a
\end{enumerate}
\item $-2x^2y^3+14x^2y^2$
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
  \item a
  \item a
\end{itemize}
\item $-2a^2b-4ab^2+8ab$

\item $2x^2+10xy-3xy-15y^2$
\item $m^2-mn-mn+n^2$
\item $2\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta-3\alpha\beta-3\beta^2$

\item $-2 x^2+13 x y-15 y^2$
\item $-5 m^2-7 m n+6 n^2$
\item $-14 p^2+29 p q+15 q^2$


\item $-2 a^2-5 a b+12 b^2$
\item $8 r^2+14 r s-15 s^2$

\item $a^2-b^2$
\item $x^2-y^2$
\item $x^2-5x+6$
\item $x^3-5x^2+6x$
\item $-10x^2+17x-3$
\item $15x^2+23x-28$

\item $-30x^2-52x+42$
\item $30x^2-52x-42$
\item $-20x^2-52x+63$
\item $20x^2-52x-63$

\item $-30x^2+12x+42$
\item $30x^2+12x-42$
\item $-20x^2+12x+63$
\item $20x^2+12x-63$

\item $30x^2-73x+42$
\item $-30x^2-73x-42$
\item $20x^2-73x+63$
\item $-20x^2-73x-63$

\item $30x^2+71x+42$
\item $-30x^2+71x-42$
\item $20x^2+71x+63$
\item $-20x^2+71x-63$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

With `\int_case:nn` (documented in [*The LaTeX3 Interfaces*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), sec. XI.5, *Integer expression conditionals*), you gain more flexibility.

```
\apptocmd\@item
  {
    \int_case:nn { \int_mod:nn{\use:c{c@\@listctr}}{3} }
      {
        {0}{ \color{red} }
        {1}{ \color{blue} }
        {2}{ \color{green} }
      }
  }
  {}{\fail}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @WissenMachtFrei, I've updated my answer to not color nested lists.

Comment: @WissenMachtFrei Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

The following does what you want, but you shouldn't nest any environment inside of an enumerate using `\autocoloredlist`!

`\autocoloredlist` has an optional argument with which you can choose which modulo you want (by default this is using `3`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@autocoloredlist@group
\newcommand*\autocoloredlist[1][3]
  {%
    \xapptocmd\@item
      {%
        \ifnum\numexpr\value{enumi}-(\value{enumi}/#1)*#1=1
          \begingroup\color{red}\@autocoloredlist@grouptrue
        \fi
        \ignorespaces
      }%
      {}{}%
    \preto\item{\if@autocoloredlist@group\endgroup\fi}{}{}%
    \preto\end{\if@autocoloredlist@group\endgroup\fi}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[first=\autocoloredlist]
\item $3xy^2-5xy$
\item $-2x^2y^3+14x^2y^2$
\item $-2a^2b-4ab^2+8ab$

\item $2x^2+10xy-3xy-15y^2$
\item $m^2-mn-mn+n^2$
\item $2\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta-3\alpha\beta-3\beta^2$

\item $-2 x^2+13 x y-15 y^2$
\item $-5 m^2-7 m n+6 n^2$
\item $-14 p^2+29 p q+15 q^2$


\item $-2 a^2-5 a b+12 b^2$
\item $8 r^2+14 r s-15 s^2$

\item $a^2-b^2$
\item $x^2-y^2$
\item $x^2-5x+6$
\item $x^3-5x^2+6x$
\item $-10x^2+17x-3$
\item $15x^2+23x-28$

\item $-30x^2-52x+42$
\item $30x^2-52x-42$
\item $-20x^2-52x+63$
\item $20x^2-52x-63$

\item $-30x^2+12x+42$
\item $30x^2+12x-42$
\item $-20x^2+12x+63$
\item $20x^2+12x-63$

\item $30x^2-73x+42$
\item $-30x^2-73x-42$
\item $20x^2-73x+63$
\item $-20x^2-73x-63$

\item $30x^2+71x+42$
\item $-30x^2+71x-42$
\item $20x^2+71x+63$
\item $-20x^2+71x-63$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image]